# Subspace of 3D Rotation Group that Provides Unique Cube Orientations

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetry

Let me begin by saying that I am a mechanical engineering student without much of a math background. I am attempting to write a program which requires a selection of unique cube orientations sampled from all orientations as uniformly as possible... no repeated orientations are allowed and the selected orientations should not be too similar (perhaps something like a minimum $5^\circ$ separation about any axis). The cube is completely uniform, so I define uniqueness between two given orientations by whether or not a symmetry transform relates them. If they are related by a symmetry transform - they are not unique.  I am aware that the cube symmetry group is quite large with 24 rotational symmetries existing for any given orientation.

In my mind, I picture the 3D rotation group as a vector space with elements $(\theta_x,\theta_y,\theta_z)$. In trying to tackle this problem, I am attempting to imagine what that vector space would look like with all the rotations that would lead to duplicate cube orientations deleted. If an asymmetric object's unique orientations completely fill the 3D rotation group space, what portions can be deleted in the case of a cubical object?

I am also aware that the 3D rotation group can be represented by the space of $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrices. Perhaps there are some ideas from linear algebra that may be directly applicable to this problem.

**More Concisely** (Thank you user7530)

For a uniform cube, define sufficiently unique cube orientations as those that have significant difference in orientation under all symmetry transformations. Does $SO(3)/O$, where $O$ is the octahedral group, have a known structure that may facilitate the selection of sufficiently unique cube orientations?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem is that I would like a fairly uniform sample of orientations that differ from each other somewhat substantially (say by at least around 5 degrees about some axis).  I think because of the symmetry of the square in your proposed method, the result would be many orientations that are very similar to each other.

Comment: To explain a bit more, in the 2D case you mention, sampling from a quarter circling would be more what I'd do as that would help to avoid close repeats due to symmetry. The question is... how do we extend such a simple solution to 3D?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want an algorithm to “evenly” sample $SO(3)/O$, where $O$ is the octahedral group… I’ll have to think about this, as I agree the problem is not as simple as it first appears!

Comment: Mathematically, the probability of picking two "equivalent random orientations" is zero, so it looks as if you might as well sample randomly from the rotation group $SO(3)$ itself. (Analogously, in the plane it's not necessary to worry about sampling from a quarter-circle; sampling randomly from the set of angles in one full turn has the same effect with less effort.) <> If that's right, it's straightforward to sample randomly from $SO(3)$.

Comment: @user7530 Yes! I think that is a concise summary of what I'm trying to do though I am not very familiar with the $/$ operator... is that just modding out $SO(3)$ by $O$?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but here is a procedure which will give you a list of "substantially different" orientations with a fairly uniform distribution: Iteratively draw random 3D orientations. For each orientation, check that none of its images under the symmetries of the cube are substantially different from any previously chosen orientations (however you define that criterion), otherwise resample. Repeat until you have enough orientations, or until the random packing is dense enough that the program struggles to find any new insertions.

Comment: What you're effectively doing here is, rather than sampling from a group quotient directly, picking a random element of the large group and computing the relevant [coset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset) as your representative. (This has the disadvantage of needing more space and being less efficient in many cases, but if your cosets are only of size $24$ then this probably won't be a big deal.)

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect You are right; I do not think a brute force procedure would be too hard. One could definitely randomly generate cubes and write some protocol to ensure that neither it or its images $O(3)$ are close to previously selected cubes. I think I'm just curious if there is a more sophisticated way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or something the program will do repeatedly? How many orientations do you expect it to be generating? Are you looking for a set of orientations that maximize how "spread out" they are (in the space of all orientations), or are you looking for a way to randomly generate a set of them which are correlated to have a "repulsion" effect? (In the latter case, they can end up close together, just with low probability.)